# Node.js with express and react, fs.readdir can't find files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, babeljs, fs

In my application I use Node.js, React and Express. I want to load pictures from directory on my disc. 
Let's say that files I want to load are in //localhost:3000/images/own/

(when I type ex. //localhost:3000/images/own/my_pic.jpg browser returns certain picture)

I used to do it with ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/images/own',
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function (data){
         //some actions here
        }
 });
```

but now I get 404 error 'GET http://localhost:3000/images/own/ 404 (Not Found)'.

I know that file loading with node is often done with fs, but as my script is written in babel (needed in React) i can't use **require('fs')**. I found https://github.com/OptimalBits/fs.js which I can use (by including it in my html file), but when using it as in the example:

```
FSFactory(1024*1024, 'images/own', function(err, fs){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }

        fs.readdir('/', function(err, entries){
            if(err)
                console.log(err);

            console.log(entries);

        });
    });
```

the fs object is empty and readdir returns empty table.

Should I give the directory path in different way or is there any other way to load files? I'm quite new to node, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you use `fs` when using Babel? Also, it reads as if you're trying to mix frontend code (React) with backend code (Express, fs) and don't know where one stops and the other continues.

Comment: I guess that there is some bug in babel and it doesn't recognize word 'require' (I get ReferenceError: require is not defined)- the only way it works is to include script tag with link to project. I may have some problems with dividing React and fs. I mean my site presents a gallery of pictures (fronend side done by React), but pics in it have to be loaded somehow and I thought fs is right thing to use. All remaining backend code (like app configuration, routes) is placed in separate .js files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by your question and your comments, I think that you're mixing up frontend and backend code.

Even though both are written in Javascript, frontend (browser) code has more restrictions imposed on it. One such restriction is the ability to read files or directories. This explains why you can't use `fs`.

Also, `require()` is not a Javascript (as in *"part of the language"*) command, but something that Node (= backend) provides to load modules. Hence, you can't use that (directly) in browsers either.

There are ways to write Node-like code targeted at browsers, where calls to `require()` get translated into something that the browser will understand. One such way is [`browserify`](http://browserify.org/). However, this still doesn't allow you to run specific backend functionality in a browser (in other words, `require('fs')` wouldn't get translated to anything useful).

Now, to get back to your actual question: if you want to read a directory on your server that contains image files, and build an image gallery from it, you need to do the directory-reading on your server.

It could work something like this:

- Your frontend code would query the server (using an AJAX call, for instance);
- The server reads the directory contents, formats them properly (for instance, to JSON), and returns them to the frontend;
- The frontend takes the data and dynamically generates the gallery.

Comment: Creating specific 'get' route in backend file and using ajax call helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When using `express`, you can tell `express` that you have a directory that needs to be accessible directly via http(s).

For example, if you have a `public` dir with your public files, you can make that "visible" this way:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

So, if you have the file `public/images/own/my_pic.jpg`, it will be accessible via http://localhost:3000/images/own/my_pic.jpg

The only caveat is that you are not getting a file listing on http://localhost:3000/images/own - you'll need to know exactly which files you need.

Comment: This is exactly what I have. I had already set app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));  and can access images separately using whole path (as I wrote in my question). But what I need is to load all files (their URLs) from this directory because they're used in a gallery.

Comment: There is a module called `serve-index` that you can use to serve the directory index.